# How does window.clear() works in SFML when making a character move in the screen?

Tags: c++, logic, sfml

Well, I've been watching a tutorial on how to use SFML. I'm currently learning to move a sprite in the screen. Before adding window.clear(); every time I moved the sprite it left like a trail, like if the sprite was a brush. Then the tutorial man said to add window.clear BEFORE window.draw(player);

Could you please explain the logic behind that? Like, the window gets cleared, then draws the character and the displays it. Here is the code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1920, 1080), "Screen", sf::Style::Default);
    sf::RectangleShape player(sf::Vector2f(100.0f, 100.0f));
    player.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    //run as long as the window is open
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event evnt;
        while (window.pollEvent(evnt)) {
            switch (evnt.type) {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            case sf::Event::Resized:
                printf("New window width: %i New window height: %i\n", evnt.size.width, evnt.size.height);
                break;
            case sf::Event::TextEntered:
                if (evnt.text.unicode < 128) {
                    printf("%c", evnt.text.unicode);
                }
            }
            // "close requested" event: we close the window
            if (evnt.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::W)){
            player.move(0.0f, -0.1f);
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::A)) {
            player.move(-0.1f, 0.0f);
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::S)) {
            player.move(0.0f, 0.1f);
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::D)) {
            player.move(0.1f, 0.0f);
        }
        window.clear();
        window.draw(player);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The logic behind [`sf::RenderWindow::clear()`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1RenderTarget.php#a6bb6f0ba348f2b1e2f46114aeaf60f26) is actually quite simple. The reason you see a trail behind the sprite without clear is because you redraw the sprite again without getting rid of the old one. Clearing the screen gets rid of anything that was already on the screen, so you end up with a blank canvas to redraw everything on in its updated position. The character, which is your sprite, isn't actually moving, it is constantly getting redrawn in a new position on the window.